# Doctrine : join on several values in a subquery

Tags: join, doctrine, in-subquery

I created a query in SQL but I don't know hos to reproduce with doctrine.
The difficulties, I would like to join on 2 values in a subquery.
Here my SQL query :

`SELECT u.nom
FROM profile p1
JOIN user u ON u.id = p1.id_user
JOIN (
    SELECT MAX(p2.annee) defyear, p2.id_user
    FROM profile p2
    GROUP BY p2.id_user
) t2 ON p1.id = t2.id_user AND p1.annee = t2.defyear
WHERE p1.att1 = 1`

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

From what I've found so far you cannot JOIN on subqueries with Querybuilder. You can however use NativeSQL as I understand.

See the thread: 
https://groups.google.com/d/msg/doctrine-user/0rNbXlD0E_8/xMNiQgp9c3QJ

and NativeQueries on: 
http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/native-sql.html

Hope this helps!